How to wait until window.location.replace( is completed?
Inside useEffect , I am calling window.location.replace
and once that completes , I need to fetch a value from cookie
useEffect(() => {
    async function fetchData() {
      try {
          let REACT_APP_LOGIN_URL = 'https://someurl/login';     
          var url = new URL(window.location.href);
          const serverLoginUrl = `${REACT_APP_LOGIN_URL}?state=${encodeURIComponent(url.toString())}`;
          window.location.replace(serverLoginUrl);
        // How can I make this wait ?
          const cookies = document.cookie?.split(';');
        const authValue = cookies.find((cookie) => cookie.includes('some-cookie'));       
        const accessToken = authValue?.split('=')[1];
      } catch (e) {
        console.log('error in fetchData' + e.message.toString());
        console.error(e);
      }
    };
    fetchData();
  }, []);

I have used await , but didn't worked

Luckily that won't work, because it seems you are trying to "steal" an accesstoken from a cookie of a different site here ...

There's no way to do that.
When window.location.replace completes, the rest of that function will not run since it's been unloaded, as you've navigated elsewhere.
